# Upgrade to Laravel 5 or use 4

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I have started making an authentication system using Laravel 4. Now should I upgrade it to Laravel 5 as there are a lot of new features or should I continue using Laravel 4?

Comment: Whether 4 or 5, it's still the same framework. :) Just a handful of differences and optimizations.

If you're asking with version you should go with for a new project right now, then I'd personally pick 5.

Comment: Here is the official documentation to do it: http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade

Comment: I recently released a service that will [upgrade your Laravel projects automatically](https://laravelshift.com). You may be interested in the *Shift* from 4.2 to 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say upgrade right now. You might end up upgrading later or continue to write code for things that laravel 5 provides out of box. Just imagine upgrading at a later stage when there are other things to break as well.

Comment: I think you are correct. There seems to be a lot of authentication out of the box. So how is everyone finding 5 over 4?

Comment: Laravel 5 is now stable, so I can't see any reason against using it.

Comment: Also note that Laravel 5.1 is a Long Term Support release and will receive security updates and bug fixes long after other versions are retired.